# How can I remove the last added <input> with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a form where the user will be able to add and remove text inputs as needed. I've made some code to add text inputs, but i can't figure out how to remove the newly added text input.

My JavaScript is as follow:

```
function addInput() {
    var antal = document.getElementById('antalfelter').value;
    var person = document.getElementById('persondiv');
    antal++;

    person.innerHTML = person.innerHTML
                       + '<input type="text" id="person' + antal + '" name="person' + antal + '"'
                       + 'style="width: 200px; height: 25px; margin-left: 15px;" value="' + antal
                       + '"><br>';                    

    document.getElementById("antalfelter").value = antal;
```

And my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="opretreferat.php" id="tilstede">
    <input type="hidden" id="antalfelter" name="antalfelter" value="1">
    <div id="persondiv">
        <input type="text" id="person" name="person1" value="1"><br>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add" name="add"
           value="Tilføj felt" onclick="addInput()"><br>
    <input type="button" id="remove" name="remove"
           value="Fjern felt" onclick="removeInput()"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="next" name="next"
           value="Næste">
</form>
```

I want to remove the last text input, unless it's the only one left.

Can anyone help me?

(Sorry for my Danish tagnames. I hope you can see through it.)

---

## **EDIT**

I've changed my JavaScript to this to get rid of line breaks:

```
function addInput() {
    var antal = document.getElementById('antalfelter').value;
    var person = document.getElementById('persondiv');
    antal++;

    person.innerHTML = person.innerHTML
                       + '<div id="persondiv' + antal + '">'
                       + '<input type="text" id="person' + antal + '" name="person' + antal + '"'
                       + 'style="width: 200px; height: 25px; margin-left: 15px;" value="' + antal
                       + '"></div>';                    

    document.getElementById("antalfelter").value = antal;
}
```

Comment: I see you defined a removeInput. Is there anything in it? Would you mind posting that? The reason I ask is we want to see what you have tried already

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")` will select all the `text` inputs on your form. Then you just need to check `length > 1` and then remove the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fiddled around with some code and i've tried to keep it simple and at last (After reading Rahil Wazir answer where he used parentNode) i've come up with this:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="opretreferat.php" id="tilstede">
    <input type="hidden" id="antalfelter" name="antalfelter" value="1">
    <div id="persondivcontainer">
        <div id="persondiv1">
            <input type="text" id="person1" name="person1"
                   style="width: 200px; height: 25px; margin-left: 15px;"
                   value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add" name="add"
           style="width: 200px; height: 25px; margin-left: 15px;"
           value="Tilføj felt" onclick="addInput()"><br>
    <input type="button" id="remove" name="remove"
           style="width: 200px; height: 25px; margin-left: 15px;"
           value="Fjern felt" onclick="removeInput()"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="next2" name="next2"
           style="width: 200px; height: 25px; margin-left: 15px;"
           value="Næste">
</form>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
function addInput() {
    var antal = document.getElementById('antalfelter').value;
    var person = document.getElementById('persondiv' + antal);

    if (antal < 6 ) {
        antal++;

        person.outerHTML = person.outerHTML
                           + '<div id="persondiv' + antal + '">'
                           + '<input type="text" id="person' + antal + '" name="person' + antal + '"'
                           + 'style="width: 200px; height: 25px; margin-left: 15px;" value="' + antal
                           + '"></div>';                    

        document.getElementById("antalfelter").value = antal;
    }
}

function removeInput() {
    var antal = document.getElementById('antalfelter').value;                    
    var person = document.getElementById('persondiv' + antal);

    if (antal > 1) {
        person.parentNode.removeChild(person);
        antal--;
    }

    document.getElementById("antalfelter").value = antal;
}
```

...and it works as it should.

I am happy for all your responses and it helped me in the right direction with my very first JavaScript.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
function removeInput() {
    var allInputs = document.getElementById('persondiv').querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'),
        totalInputs = allInputs.length;
    if (totalInputs > 1) {
        allInputs[totalInputs - 1].parentNode.removeChild(allInputs[totalInputs - 1]);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu38g/2/)

Comment: This is a nice and clean solution.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I am looking for. A clean simple solution for my problem. Only tow problems... I don't know how it is working. This is my very first time making my own JavaScript and how can i make it remove a complete div instead.

Comment: @Henrikmon You can just do like this: `document.getElementById('persondiv').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('persondiv'))`

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you'd build up the DOM dynamically, rather than using innerHTML. However, it is still possible this way:

```
function removeLastInput()
{
    //  find all <input> tags:
    var inputs = document.getElementById('persondiv').getElementsByTagName("input")

    //  find the last one that's valid:
    var i = inputs.length
    do {
        i --
        var lastInput = inputs[i]
    } while(i > 0 && lastInput.type !== "text")

    //  if the correct one wasn't found, quit:
    if(i <= 0 || lastInput.type !== "text") return;

    //  remove it via the parentNode:
    lastInput.parentNode.removeChild(lastInput)
}
```

Comment: Two things, the last `input` element here are the buttons. You need to restrict it to `input` with `type="text"`. Second, you need to check that there is more than one since they don't want to remove the last one.

Comment: Did some quick testing with the code that's up here now. Seems to be working fine to me, but I'd be happy to get some possible bugs out of there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HC3uL/3/) I created that might help with what you are trying to do.  I also took  it a step forward and gave you the ability to remove any person input field in a list.  I tried to document the best I could to help you understand what I was doing and trying to accomplish.  Hope this helps.

Here is a little snippet of the code:

```
function removeLastPerson(){
     var lastIndex = getNumberOfPeople() - 1;
     removePerson(lastIndex);
}

function getNumberOfPeople(){
    //this is counting all of the input fields inside of the person div.
    return $("#person input").size();
}

function removePerson(index){
    if ( getNumberOfPeople() === 1 ){
        alert("Cannot remove the last person input box");
        return false;
    }

    if (index < 0){
        alert("There are no people to remove.");
        return false;
    }

    //instead of using <br /> tags i used div tags since div tags do make a new line.  When you remove a person input the <br /> tags were left.
    $("#person_" + index + "_tag").remove(); 
    reIndex(); //reindex is needed when removing a specific person input field in a list of input fields.  See JsFiddle to see what is going on in the reIndex function
}
```